# Se superponen las url en Django

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, django

Tengo un app con un formulario de carga de productos de libros (Producto, Fecha de publicación, archivo). Después de la carga genera su propio URL (http://127.0.0.1:8000/vistaprevia/5/ver/).

Pero al seleccionar ver todas las imágenes, me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`verimagenes.html`:

```
{% extends "vistaprevia/plantilla.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Ver todas las imagenes</h2>
         </div>
    </div>

    <main class="container">
        <div class="row" >
            <section class="col-12" style="padding:30px; 30px; 230px; 30px;">
                 {% for productos in productos %}
                     <a href="{% url 'ver' productos.id %}">
                     <img src="/media/{{productos.ruta_imagen}}" alt="My Image" width="20%">
                     </a>
                 {% endfor %}
            </section>
        </div>
     </main>

{% endblock %}
```

Archivo `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from vistaprevia import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^cargar/$', views.cargar_imagen, name='cargar'),
        url(r'^(?P<producto_id>\d+)/ver/$', views.ver_imagen, name='ver'),
        url(r'^verimagenes/$', views.verimagenes, name='verimagenes'),
    ]
```

Archivo `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from vistaprevia.models import Producto
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from vistaprevia.forms import CargarForm
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

#def index(request):
#   return HttpResponse("Hola Mundo!.")

def index(request):
    contenido = {'nombre_sitio': 'LibrosOnline'}
    para_minorista = {'tipo_usuario' : 'minorista' , 'incremento' : '25'}
    para_mayorista = {'tipo_usuario': 'mayorista', 'incremento': '10'}
    return render(request, 'vistaprevia/index.html', {'contenido':contenido,
            'para_minorista' : para_minorista, 'para_mayorista' : para_mayorista})

def cargar_imagen(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CargarForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            producto = form.cleaned_data['producto']
            fecha_publicacion = form.cleaned_data['fecha_publicacion']
            ruta_imagen = form.cleaned_data['ruta_imagen']
            newdoc = Producto(producto=producto, fecha_publicacion=fecha_publicacion,
                          ruta_imagen=ruta_imagen)
            newdoc.save()
            return redirect("verimagenes")
        else:
            return render(request, 'vistaprevia/formulario.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = CargarForm()
    return render(request, 'vistaprevia/formulario.html', {'form':form})

def ver_imagen(request, producto_id):
    try:
    producto = Producto.objects.get(pk=producto_id)

    except Producto.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('vistaprevia/verimagen.html',{
                'producto': producto,
               'error_message' : "No has seleccionado un producto.",
                },content_type=RequestContext(request))

def verimagenes(request):
    try:
        productos = Producto.objects.all()

    except Producto.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    return render_to_response('vistaprevia/verimagenes.html',{
                'productos': productos,
               'error_message' : "No has seleccionado un producto.",
                },content_type=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: La url que se muestra en el navegador es la url que se genera al pulsar ver imagenes?
Es raro hay un { en la url?

Comment: si. queda asi: 127.0.01:8000/vistaprevia/5/ver/{/vistaprevia/verimagenes/

Comment: yo creo que ese es el problema, segun el error, solo hay url para 127.0.01:8000/vistaprevia/5/ver/
Esta parte no concuerda con ninguna url, por eso dice que no existe.
{/vistaprevia/verimagenes/

Comment: {% for productos in productos %}
                     <a href="{% url 'ver' productos.id %}">
                     <img src="/media/{{productos.ruta_imagen}}" alt="My Image" width="20%">
                     </a>
                 {% endfor %}
{% for producto in productos %}
se estan confundiendo las variebles. Luego cambias todos los productos por producto

Comment: ah ok. lo probaré. gracias

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer en el html estas generando una confusion de nombres de variables
Puedes intentar con este fragmento, lo único que se hace es renombrar la variable de for productos por producto, ya que el arreglo se llama productos también.

```
{% extends "vistaprevia/plantilla.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Ver todas las imagenes</h2>
         </div>
    </div>

    <main class="container">
        <div class="row" >
            <section class="col-12" style="padding:30px; 30px; 230px; 30px;">
                 {% for producto in productos %}
                     <a href="{% url 'ver' producto.id %}">
                     <img src="/media/{{producto.ruta_imagen}}" alt="My Image" width="20%">
                     </a>
                 {% endfor %}
            </section>
        </div>
     </main>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: encontre la falla en verimagen.py el href decia:  <a href="{{% url 'verimagenes' %}">Ver todas las imagenes</a> es decir, tenia un corchete de mas.

Comment: Ok, me alegra que hayas podido solucionar tú error. Eso nos deja de experiencia en una proxima preguntar colocar todo el código.